# Java Reflection - listing properties (getters & setters) of a class

Tags: java, android, reflection

```
public class foo
{
    private String _name;
    private String _bar;

    public String getName() {
        return _name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        _name = name;
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return _bar;
    }

    public void setBarn(String bar) {
        _bar = bar;
    }
}
```

If I have the above class can I use reflection to list the properties defined by the getters and setters? I've tried the method below but it doesn't work, `Field[] fields` is left empty. I know I can do this in .Net but Java is a very different animal. Am I barking up the wrong tree altogether?

```
private HashMap<String, String> getHashMap(Object obj) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Class<?> cls = obj.getClass();

    Field fields[] = cls.getFields();
    for(Field f : fields) {
        String name = f.getName();
        String value = f.get(obj).toString();
        map.put(name, value);
    }
    return map;
}
```

*Also* setters and getters maybe evil, should I just drop this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use `cls.getDeclaredFields` instead ? (And `f.setAccessible(true)` before get private field).

If you want getter and setter you have to get method by `getDeclaredMethods`. Then I suggest using [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) instead of writing your own reflection logic :) (IMHO less convenient is [java.beans.Introspector](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html)).

Comment: Thanks zacheusz. That will work but it will list all the private fields, not just the ones exposed by getters and setters. In reality my class will have more than _name and _bar.

Comment: If you want getter and setter you have to get method by `getDeclaredMethods`. I suggest using [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) instead ;) It could be better coz e.g. in Java getters for boolean can start with `is` and `get`.

Comment: These seems the most feasible, it's actually the dalvik vm and unfortunately Introspector isn't available (otherwise I'd have gone with that).

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) class. Obtain the BeanInfo and use [getPropertyDescriptors()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html#getPropertyDescriptors%28%29) method. That should get you on the way.

Comment: Agreed, I would resort to other libraries as well. There are a couple out there. Spring for instance is something most of us already have present at the class path. Though for stackoverflow I do like the point to the language native functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
List<Method> methods = Arrays.asList(getClass().getDeclaredMethods());
for (Method m : methods)
{
    String name = m.getName();
    if (name.startsWith("get") || name.startsWith("is"))
    {
        // Do something with the getter method
    } else if (name.startsWith("set"))
    {
        // Do something with the setter method
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing methods (e.g. booleans 'isXxx') and including to much (e.g. get named method with params and set methods with multiple params). I would therefor not recommend such approach.

Comment: and getter for boolean can start with `is`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't suit me. For instance if I have a class with 5 or 6 fields, which is quite feasible, then I'll end up with a load of if statements.